# Set multiple recurring billing cycle option for a product

Tags: products, recurring, billing, billing-agreements

Is there a way to set multiple billing cycle options for a product? For Instance, a product having  billing options for every 2 months, quarterly or yearly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a [demo](http://demo.cryozonic.com/subscriptions/coffee-beans.html) of [this module](http://store.cryozonic.com/magento-extensions/stripe-subscriptions.html).

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to do, I have purchased the product and it works fine.Thanks a lot.